# C++ compiler picking the wrong overload of a class member function

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

I have this code:

```
template <class T>
class Something
{
    T val;
public:
    inline Something() : val() {}
    inline Something(T v) : val(v) {}
    inline T& get() const { return val; }

    inline Something& operator =(const Something& a) { val = a.val; return *this; }
};

typedef Something<int> IntSomething;
typedef Something<const int> ConstIntSomething;

class Other
{
public:
    IntSomething some_function()
    {
        return IntSomething(42);
    }

    ConstIntSomething some_function() const
    {
        return ConstIntSomething(42);
    }
};

void wtf_func()
{
    Other o;
    ConstIntSomething s;
    s = o.some_function();
}
```

However, the compiler picks the wrong overload of `Other::some_function()` in `wtf_func()` (i.e. the non-const one). How can I fix this? Note that for certain reasons I cannot change the name of `Other::some_function()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`o` is not const-qualified, so the non-const `some_function` is selected.  If you want to select the const-qualified overload, you need to add the const qualifier to `o`:

```
Other o;
Other const& oref(o);
ConstIntSomething s;
s = oref.some_function();
```

When overload resolution occurs, the compiler only looks at the `o.some_function()` subexpression; it does not look at the context around the function call to decide to pick something else.  Further, the return type of a member function is not considered during overload resolution.

Note that it may make more sense for `IntSomething` to be implicitly convertible to `ConstIntSomething`, either using an `operator ConstIntSomething()` overload in `IntSomething` (less good) or using a non-explicit `ConstIntSomething(IntSomething const&)` constructor in `ConstIntSomething` (more good).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't pick the wrong overload; `const`-ness is resolved by whether `this` is `const` or not.  In your case, `o` is non-`const`, so the non-`const` overload is picked.

You can hack this by creating a const-reference to `o`, e.g.:

```
const Other &o2 = o;
s = o2.some_function();
```

But really, you should probably be considering your overloads in `Something`.  For instance, you can't currently do this:

```
IntSomething x;
ConstIntSomething y;
y = x;
```

which doesn't sound correct.  Why shouldn't you be allowed to take a const ref to a non-const ref?

Answer (score 1):

Your object `o` needs to be `const` object for a `const` function to be called on it.  Otherwise the compiler rightly picks up the non const version of the function.

Comment: This is a little misleading because you can have a non-`const` object with `const` member functions and you can call them.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: True, Just to make it clear. You can call const member functions on a non const object but you cannot call non-const member functions on a const object.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler picks the overload to use based on the constness of the object that will become `this`. You can make it call the desired version with `static_cast`: `s = static_cast<const Other&>(o.some_function());`

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to copy the new behaviour found in the containers of the C++0x standard library. Containers such as vector now have members `cbegin()` and `cend()` that return a const_iterator whether the container is const or not unlike `begin()` and `end()`

```
class Other {
    // Rest of other
public:
    // No overload for non-const
    // Even if called with a non const Other, since this member is marked
    // const, this will be of type Other const * in all cases and will call
    // the const qualified overload of some_function.
    ConstIntSomething csome_function() const
    {
        return some_function();
    }
};
```